# Sphinx doesn't render syntax highlighting when using the @ infix operator for matrix multiplication

Tags: python-3.5, python-sphinx

Python 3.5 implements the @ infix operator for matrix multiplication in accordance with [PEP 465](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465) .

Let A and B be 2 numpy arrays:

```
A = numpy.array([[1],[2]])
B = numpy.array([[1,2]])
```

Then, the compact form:

```
C = A @ B
```

is equivalent to:

```
C = numpy.dot(A,B)
```

My problem is that when I use sphinx (v1.3.6), a literalinclude such as the one described later doesn't consider the script as a Python one and does not render the syntax highlighting:

```
.. literalinclude:: toto.py
    :linenos:
    :language: python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygments has a special lexer for Python 3. See http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#pygments.lexers.python.Python3Lexer.

It should work if you use `python3` or `py3` as the language:

```
.. literalinclude:: toto.py
   :linenos:
   :language: python3
```